# ASP.NET saving empty date value in SQL Server database with parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date, webforms, null

I have a web forms application which allows to update database columns. One of the database columns is `Finish Date` which is of `date` datatype in the SQL Server database.

I use SQL query with parameters and textbox to provide the new value for the finish date.

This is a code which gets me the value of the date from a text box within the grid:

```
TextBox tFD = (TextBox)grdProjectUpdate.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].FindControl("proFDTextBox");
```

then I use a parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@proFD", SqlDbType.Date).Value = tFD.Text.Trim();
```

to update the value using this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE PMSprojects SET proFD = @proFD ,...
```

This solution works fine whenever there is an actual date provided. However, it does not save nulls. If I provide an empty string, it is being converted into `1900-01-01` date, even though the column in the database allows nulls.

How could I solve this issue and save null to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write code around this to handle, and pass `DbNull.Value` when the value is null.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@proFD", SqlDbType.Date).Value = (tFD.Text.Trim().Length > 0) ? (object)tFD.Text.Trim() : DbNull.Value;
```